# Counts of complex conitions including strings in R

Tags: r

Again I need help with a problem.

I have a database with with multiple rows and columns.
I have found a way to count the number of rows corrseponding to custom conditions.

The code is built as a custom function so that I can customize it with the variable "mit". "x" is the dataframe. Var is the variable returned by the function.

I am using summarise and n_distinict to count only one row per Name (=Név).

```
MACI <- function(x, mit) {
  var <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(mit)) {
    var <- var + summarise(x, count = n_distinct(Név[
      MACI == 0 & (
        x$Minta.csoport.kód == mit[i,1]
      )
      ]))
  }
```

Now what I need is to find rows that contain a specific string. I want to count all that has Acinetobacter in it (that includes "Acinetobacter baumannii", "Acinetobacter spp.", and other Acinetobacters) I have tried str_detect but no luck.

```
 var3 <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(mit)) {
    var3 <- var3 + nrow(filter(
        str_detect(x$Mikróba.Név, "Acinetobacter")
        & 
        x$Minta.csoport.kód == mit[i,1]
      ))
  }
```

Any other suggestion?

Comment: You probably don't need a loop to do what you want. str_detect() takes vectors. Since it returns a logical, you could combine those logical vectors to find lines that match both conditions.

Comment: I am using a loop as I am calling the function with various "mit"-s

Comment: Would be easier if you gave example datasets for ```x``` and ```mit```.  See stackoverflow guidance on creating a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks. Reposted with example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58999694/r-counts-corresponding-to-complex-conditions-including-strings