# R - counts corresponding to complex conditions including strings

Tags: r

This is a repost.
I have a database with with multiple rows and columns. I have found a way to count the number of rows corresponding to custom conditions.
Now I have trouble with counts of custom strings, such as all strings that contain "Pseudomonas". That would include Pseudomonas aeruginosa, Pseudomonas spp., etc.

Sample (the actual table consists of 5000 rows and 200 columns):

```
John - 4  - Staphylococcus - T
John - 4  - Pseudomonas aeruginosa -T
Jack - 5  - Pseudomonas spp. - T
Mary - 4  - Klebsiella - F
Mary - 5  - Pseudomonas kompl. - T
Mary - 4  - Escherichia Coli - F
Louise- 3 - Pseudomonas constell
```

I would like to find the count of those:
- has the string "Pseudomonas" in it
- Column2 is 4
- only one count per person counts

As I will need to run the script several times on similarly structured datasets with different values I am using a custom function ("MACI"). "x" is the dataframe. "Var" is the variable returned by the function. I am using summarise and n_distinict to count only one row per Name. "c2" variable with which the function is called is used to customise which data from column 2 I need.

This worked so far, but no luck with finding strings within strings.

```
MACI <- function(x, c2) {
  var <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(c2)) {
    var <- var + summarise(x, count = n_distinct(Name[
      MACI == 0 & (
        x$column2 == c2[i,1]
      )
      ]))
  }
#return
  return(var)
}
```

What I attempted with string and did not work:

```
  var3 <- 0
  x2 <- subset(x, str_detect(x$Name, "Acinetobacter*"))
  for (i in 1:nrow(mit)) {
    var3 <- var3 + summarise(x2, count = n_distinct(Name[

        x2$column2 == c2[i,1]

    ]))
  }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked up reproducible examples in R? There is a really good explanation by Hadley Wickham [here](https://gist.github.com/hadley/270442) which might help you to understand what people are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

The data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "John - 4  - Staphylococcus - T
                         John - 4  - Pseudomonas aeruginosa -T
                         Jack - 5  - Pseudomonas spp. - T
                         Mary - 4  - Klebsiella - F
                         Mary - 5  - Pseudomonas kompl. - T
                         Mary - 4  - Escherichia Coli - F
                         Louise- 3 - Pseudomonas constell", 
                 sep = "-",fill=TRUE)
```

The code:

```
aggregate(V3~V1,df,function(x)sum(grepl("Pseudomonas",x)))

     V1 V3
1  Jack   1
2  John   1
3 Louise  1
4  Mary   1
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be not the most elegant answer but I think it works.

Create sample data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(name= c('John','John','Jack','Mary','Mary','Mary','Louise'),
count=c(4,4,5,4,5,4,3), 
bacteria=c('Staphylococcus', 'Pseudomonas aeruginosa' , 'Pseudomonas spp.', 'Klebsiella', 'Pseudomonas kompl.', 'Escherichia coli', 'Pseudomonas constell'), 
var=c('T','T','F','T','F','F','T'))
```

Use grep to find the pattern:

```
results <- df[ grep ('Pseudomonas', df$bacteria, ignore.case=T),'name']

NROW(results)
```

Because the results are levels in 'name', repeated names are not counted.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are looking for, you are trying to count up rows that meet 3 conditions:

1. The value in column 2 is equal to 4
2. The string in column 3 contains matches a variable
3. Only counting unique values from column 1

```
# Using your example data
library(readr)
library(stringr)

dt <- read_delim (
      "John - 4  - Staphylococcus - T
      John - 4  - Pseudomonas aeruginosa -T
      Jack - 5  - Pseudomonas spp. - T
      Mary - 4  - Klebsiella - F
      Mary - 5  - Pseudomonas kompl. - T
      Mary - 4  - Escherichia Coli - F
      Louise- 3 - Pseudomonas constell",
      delim = "-", 
      col_names = F
)
dt$X2 <- as.integer(dt$X2)
dt
# # A tibble: 7 x 4
#  X1                X2 X3                         X4   
#  <chr>          <int> <chr>                      <chr>
# 1 "John "            4 " Staphylococcus "         " T" 
# 2 "      John "      4 " Pseudomonas aeruginosa " T    
# 3 "      Jack "      5 " Pseudomonas spp. "       " T" 
# 4 "      Mary "      4 " Klebsiella "             " F" 
# 5 "      Mary "      5 " Pseudomonas kompl. "     " T" 
# 6 "      Mary "      4 " Escherichia Coli "       " F" 
# 7 "      Louise"     3 " Pseudomonas constell"    <NA> 

detect <- function(x, mit) {
### following your example
     y <- x[str_detect(x$X3, mit),] %>%
            filter(X2 == 4)
     n_distinct(y$X1)
}
```

> detect(dt, "Pseudomonas")

[1] 1

> detect(dt, "Staph")

[1] 1

> detect(dt, "Acinetobacter")

[1] 0